# AS3 for Air events issues

Tags: actionscript-3, events, actionscript, air

I'm having a bit of a problem understanding why some events don't fire when calling a function from within another function.

Here's what happens and I can't figure out why:
when there is no test.xml file in the app storage directory writecamfile() executes, but then it seems the oncomplete() function never fires. the preloader remains visible and the trace does not work.
if the file exists, readcamfile() fires just fine, oncomplete hides the preloader and returns the trace.

My question is why doesn't oncomplete() fire when there is no test.xml file?
My logic was to check for the file if it does not exist, create it and then read it.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance and have a great day!

Tony

```
    package util
    {
    import flash.filesystem.*;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MediaEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.media.CameraUI;    
    import flash.media.MediaPromise;
    import flash.media.MediaType;
    import fl.containers.*;
    import fl.controls.*;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

    dynamic public class cam5 extends MovieClip
    {
    public var preloader:MovieClip;
    public function cam5()
    {
        var tmp_file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('test.xml');
        if (tmp_file.exists)
        {// File exists
            preloader.visible = true;
            readcamfile(null); // check settings from the camera file

        } else
        {// File doesn't exist
            writecamfile();
            preloader.visible = true;
        }
        function readcamfile(event:Event):void
        {
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('test.xml').url));
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, oncomplete);
        }

        function writecamfile():void
        {
            var xmlstr:XML = <images></images>;
            var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("test.xml");
            var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            var outputString:String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n';
            outputString += xmlstr.toXMLString();
            fileStream.writeUTFBytes(outputString);
            fileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, readcamfile);
            fileStream.close();         
        }

        function oncomplete(event:Event):void
        {
            var xml:XML = new XML(event.currentTarget.data);

            var chkcount : Boolean = (xml.children().length() > 0);

            if(chkcount)
            {
                var xmlcount:int = xml.children().length(); //test children count
                var camXMLList:XMLList = xml.img;
                var count:int = camXMLList.length(); //test list count

                for(var i:int=0; i<xmlcount; i++)
                {
                    var _row = xml.children()[i];
                }
                preloader.visible = false;
                trace(_row.text()+'\n'+xmlcount+'\n'+count);
            }else
            {
                preloader.visible = false;
                trace("no images");
            }

        }           
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#eventSummary) says:

> When a File object is opened synchronously, the caller pauses while the requested data is read from or written to the underlying file.

You add the listener after the synchronous write operation finished.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually figured this one out.
Instead of adding an event listner on writecamfile you can just reinitialize a call to readcamfile after you close the stream like so:

```
fileStream.close();
readcamfile();
```

if you do need to keep the event:Event parameter in your functions you might have to reinit the function like this:

```
readcamfile(null);
```

since the function is expecting a parameter